# Formless FB Sign-up

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So I have FB connect working using the PHPSDK. For starters I made it so when a user signs up, it automatically creates their profile (profile img, full name, age, gender, job/employer, email, etc.)

So it works great, one click and the profile is created.

However I'm attempting to make it so when a user clicks the Sign-up with Facebook button it additionally stores the users data in the background with the back-end. Would I have to do it via a submit form button and define all the variables below as $_POST to store it? (I'm using PDO/MySQL to do so, **See below for example**)

I tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
$user = "xxxx";
$pwd = "xxxx";

$odb = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxxx;", $user, $pwd);

$q = "INSERT INTO users(u_fullname, age, u_location, u_gender, u_bday, u_employer, u_job) VALUES(:u_fullname, :age, :u_location, :u_firstname, :u_gender, :u_bday, :u_employer, :u_job)";
$query = $odb->prepare($q);
$results = $query->execute(array(":u_fullname" => $u_fullname, ":age" => $age, ":u_location" => $u_location, ":u_gender" => $u_gender, ":u_bday" => $u_bday, ":u_employer" => $u_employer, ":u_job" => $u_job));
```

Here's the profile set-up

```
<? $fbuid = $user_profile['id'];
$u_employer = $user_profile['work'][0]['employer']['name'];
$u_job = $user_profile['work'][0]['position']['name'];
$u_firstname = $user_profile['first_name'];
$u_fullname = $user_profile['name'];
$u_location = $user_profile['location']['name'];
$u_gender = ucfirst($user_profile['gender']);
$u_bday = $user_profile['birthday'];
//explode the date to get month, day and year
$u_bday = explode("/", $u_bday);
//get age from date or birthdate
$age = (date("md", date("U", mktime(0, 0, 0, $u_bday[0], $u_bday[1], $u_bday[2]))) > date("md") ? ((date("Y")-$u_bday[2])-1):(date("Y")-$u_bday[2]));?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What kind of help do you need?

Comment: For whatever reason the profile data isn't storing into the db. I was curious if someone who had more knowledge on the subject than me could point out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: so is it retrieved from facebook?

Comment: Yeah it's retrieved/echo'ed no problem.

Comment: so how the question is related to facebook (and it takes 95% of the whole question) then if what you cannot do is to deal with database?

Comment: Because it deals with the facebook sign-in, people with the fb api experience may have already developed something they may want to share that could help me. anyways I edited the fb category out because the problem itself is unrelated to facebook.

Comment: so if you *already* get the data from FB successfully, why is it relevant? Would it be a different problem if you couldn't save the data *from file* into the database?

Comment: Forget the fb relevancy. I acknowledged and expressed that it was irrelevant to fb & removed this question from it being displayed in that category. 

My db works already, it's nothing of that sort. The table is set up correctly. It's definitely a code related issue. 

The only other alternative I can logically think of to my knowledge is to solve the problem by passing all the fb data retained into $_POST PHP variables instead.

Comment: localize the issue first. Find the exact place and exact reason why the data isn't inserted into the database. For that take `var_dump()` and check that every variable has the expected value.

Comment: So I dumped the variables and all the values we're fine. However I added ini_set("display_errors") now it's returning these errors. 

Notice: Array to string conversion in

Comment: Fixed the errors, and it's still not inserting. 

So I just created a little test on the $results variable that echos 0 if it's null and 1 if it's not. It's returning 0 so the problem is $q. So I think the problem is the data isn't passing to the placeholder for whatever reason. I just tried using $stmt->bindValue(':u_fullname', $u_fullname,':age',$age,':u_location',$u_location,':u_gender',$u_gender,':u_bday',$u_bday,':u_employer',$u_employer,':u_job',$u_job);
$stmt->execute(); and no luck :(